# Is there a way to have a migration file in flyway be applied on a developer machine but not on a production box?

Tags: database-migration, flyway

When a I am developing a new feature for my application that uses a lot of new tables the table definitions are not stable until after a few days of development. I want to check in these unstable migration files into source control WITHOUT having them be applied on the production box, when i deploy bug fixes of the same code base.

Is there a way to have a migration file in flyway be applied on a developer machine but not on a production box?

I don't like feature branches so I want to avoid feature branches they are just too much effort for me to maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I am using Spring 3.1 I was able to solve my problem using the spring profiles, to detect what environment the code is in. Here is how the solution works.

- `db.migrations` is where the production migrations go
- `dev.db.migrations` is where the development migrations go. During initial development of a new feature when tables are changing every hour or so, the migration file gets added to `dev.db.migrations` and checked into source control, it gets created on developer machines. Developer will typically blow away the test db and recreate it with sample data, so no harm in constantly changing the files in `dev.db.migrations` it also gives developers a chance to grab a version number for their changes, since they will checkin their file into source control.

below is the XML for spring profiles flyway configuration that I used.

```
<!-- =========================Configure Flyway ========================= -->
<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="locations" ref="flyway-migration-locations" />
</bean>

<!-- ========================= Development Profile Configuration ========================= -->
<beans profile="development">
    <bean id="flyway-migration-locations" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>db.migration</value>
                <value>dev.db.migration</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>

<!-- ========================= Production Profile Configuration ========================= -->
<beans profile="production">
    <bean id="flyway-migration-locations" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>db.migration</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```